# Django ORM get Latest version of each row (Inner Join)

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a table (short version ofcourse) like the following

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|id  | Simulation_Name  | Simulation_Version | sim_key |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | MySim1           | 1                  | 10      |
| 2  | MySim1           | 2                  | 10      |
| 3  | MySim2           | 1                  | 11      |
| 4  | MySim2           | 2                  | 11      |          
--------------------------------------------------------
```

On the Front End, I just want to display the latest version for each simulation. I'd appreciate any help on how to do this using Django ORM. I know there is a Max field but that only works with dates..
Currently, I'm using Raw SQL with an inner join to achieve this.
Any pointers on ORM? Thanks in advance

This is how I do it right now,

```
SELECT  *                                   
FROM  
simulation_table AS A INNER JOIN 
(SELECT id, max(simulation_version) as max_version 
from  
simulation_table 
group by sim_key) AS B 
ON 
A.sim_key= B.sim_keyAND A.simulation_version= B.simulation_version
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Max` should work with integers:

```
from django.db.models import Max
simulations = Simulation.objects.values('name').annotate(max_version=Max('version'))
```

Comment: hmmm...wonder what I was doing wrong!. Thanks though, that worked!